# If Statement and Function (Basic) keep track on divs innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, innerhtml

Ok so I have a function set up already and it gets added in the div as numbers and letters

```
"var elCamLocation = $( "TEST" )"
```

Right! 
Now I want to use a function to keep track on what is in the innerHTML of the "TEST" div and if the contents of the div changes to "0.00x2.00z0.00" then I want it to do something for example lets just say change url to keep it simple.

Here is what I have..

```
var Numbs = getElementById("TEST").innerHTML;

    function TE()
    {

    if(Numbs = "0.00x2.00z0.00")
    {
    window.location.assign("http://google.com")
    }


    };
```

But it isn't working the `window.location.assign("http://google.com")`isn't triggering at all
any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is for assignment. You should test for equality using the `===` operator.

```
if(Numbs === "0.00x2.00z0.00")
{
    //etc.
}
```